# Make transition work with SVG and JS

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have this problem that I just can't solve.

I'm doing a menu and I want to have a cool open/close button so I made a SVG file and made everything pretty.

```
.icon-grid {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  fill: #000;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mateuszrybin/0n78dg30/
press the button.

Problem I'm having that just can't make the fill transition work between black and red. The color just pops. It works for the rotation but not for the fill, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You don't need to use JS to animate the icon.  You can do that part with CSS animations.  You will then be able to have your fill animate as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the SVG DOM API. There's a  good tutorial on [here](https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/). Just read through it. Everything is explained really well.